# Create a Multi Value Field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to create a site column that resembles the characteristics of the URL Site Column, where the column has two fields in one (Title, URL). I would like to create a column for approvals that has the fields (Approval, Approved By, Approved On & Signature). I would like this to be a site column so it any user can add it to any list/library. Can anyone lead me in the right direction.

Using SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1):

You should create site content type(a content type contains multiple fields as you want) according to your description, so users could add this content type to list.

Check [official guideline](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-customize-a-site-content-type-27eb6551-9867-4201-a819-620c5658a60f).

Comment: I need this field to be used multiple times in a form, like in a single form there can be multiple URL columns. I need to create multiple Approvals